# Scopes in MySQL & Derived tables

Tags: mysql, scope, subquery, sql-function

Let's say I have 2 Tables
One named Baskets,
Another named Fruits.

Baskets-
basket_id , basket_name
1         - Basket One
2         - Basket Two

Fruits-
fruit_id , basket_id , fruit_name
1        - 1         - Banana
2        - 1         - Apple
3        - 2         - Pear

`SELECT * FROM baskets

JOIN (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(fruit_id SEPARATOR ', ') FROM fruits WHERE baskets.basket_id=fruits.basket_id) AS der_fruits

ON baskets.basket_id=der_fruits.basket_id`

Now with this query I want to get 2 rows (since there are 2 baskets) with a list of the fruit id's in it.

Like this:
basket_id, fruits
1        - 1, 2
2        - 3

But just now what I get is this:
basket_id, fruits
2        - 1, 2, 3

The thing is, I have to pass the global baskets.basket_id value in the DERIVED table.
Is there anything like a global scope in MySQL?
Or is there a way to pass the global baskets.basket_id value in a variable inside that derived table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT baskets.*,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fruits.fruit_name)
         FROM fruits f
        WHERE b.basket_id = f.basket_id) AS der_baskets
 FROM baskets b
```

The fruits are a subquery. I don't understand why you define the relationship twice. Is there something you are trying to do I don't understand?

Comment: Well, actually what I'm trying to do is create a homepage for a social networking website where I want to show all the feeds with the comments for each feed and the users that has liked each feed. I've been able to list all the feeds with the appropriate comments for each one of them. I don't want to go like 100 times to get each comment and likes and so forth so what I am trying to do is get all the information with 1 big query. Now I've done it with 2 query's.
Btw. thanks for your reaction.